# Для чего нужен 'as', 'uses' в Laravel

Tags: laravel

Объясните, пожалуйста, каково назначение 'as' и 'uses'. Не понимаю принцип этих слов.

```
Route::get('user/profile', array('as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'UserController@showProfile'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as` - работает как приставка к route, в Вашем случае лучше просто заменить `as` на метод `name`:

```
Route::get('user/profile', array('uses' => 'UserController@showProfile'))->name('profile');
```

Если же Вы оставили бы `'as' => 'profile'` и написали бы `name('profile')` то в итоге route name получился бы `profileprofile`.

`uses` - говорит какой использовать контроллер и метод, в Вашем случае это тоже не нужно, проще сделать так:

```
Route::get('user/profile', 'UserController@showProfile')->name('profile');
```

Проще и понятней.

UPD. Про метод `name` и как его использовать описано в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#named-routes)

Comment: Так, как я понимаю, при переходе по ссылке /user/profile, в контроллере UserController будет выполняться метод (функция) showProfile. А метод name('profile') для чего нужен? Где прописать?

Comment: Как я в примере дал выше, метод name нужен чтобы создавать url по name, к примеру захотите Вы поменять ссылку, и придется искать везде где была эта ссылка и менять на новую, вот name позволяет от этого избавиться, прочитайте в документации: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#named-routes (это английская, в русской тоже должно быть)